# Delete All SQL Server Linked Servers on single server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (ssms.exe) connected with a local SQL Server 2000, so I notice that every time I try enter on Linked Server option It crash inmediatly so I want to delete all the servers linkeds there for try again.

What script should I use or what command on T-SQL I have to run for delete all and without specifying  the name of each server linked.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute `sp_dropserver` for all linked servers using the database cursor. The following example shows how to do this.

```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
        select 'sp_dropserver ''' + [name] + '''' from sys.servers

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @sql   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   

           EXEC (@sql)

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @sql   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: After select 'sp_dropserver ''' + [name] + '''' from sys.servers... you can add WHERE is_linked = 1

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only delete on linked server at a time, using `sp_dropserver`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx

You could call `sp_linkedservers`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189519.aspx

reading the returned list into a temporary table, and then loop through that table, calling `sp_dropserver` for each element.

Comment: How can I do the second option? Its sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

While connected to the server:

```
select 'exec sp_dropServer ''' + name + '''', * from sys.servers where is_linked = 1
```

run the outputted first column. win.

This also allows you to pick and choose which server you want to get rid of. It is probably hanging on the connection, getting garbage it doesn't know how to handle back from a server, or a corrupted link driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just arbitrarily delete all the linked servers from every server. You'll have to (at a minimum) open a connection to each server and run some form of script or command for each linked server. If you want to know how to write a script to drop all linked servers, I suggest that you start by looking at [`sp_linkedservers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238819(SQL.80).aspx) and [`sp_dropserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933295(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: That isn't what the OP asked. They want to drop all the LS from a single server.

Comment: @EricHiggins - Sure it is... they'll need to run a command for each linked server, specifically, `sp_dropserver`. I'll say this isn't a great answer since I didn't write the script FOR the OP, but it definitely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error message when it is crashing?
Also what is the service pack of that corresponding SQL 2000 server?

I would rather fix this tools issue than simply recreating them a fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Version without a cursor. server_id=0 is the local server not a linked server.

```
--remove all linked servers    
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

while exists (select 1 from sys.servers where server_id>0)
begin
    select @sql= N'sp_dropserver ' + [name] from sys.servers where server_id>0  
    exec (@sql)
end
```